# How to publish an Asp.Net MVC 2 application using commandline?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, publish

In Visual Studio 2010 we can right click a Web application and select Publish from the Menu. Using this we can publish a web application to a File System.

How can we achieve the same using Command line?

**EDIT**: Although we can use xcopy as suggested it is not same as Publish command as we have to manually exclude unnecessary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to publish using the command line.

If using MSBuild then you need the [AspNetCompiler Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx).

The options the Aspnet_compiler provides are the same as those provided by Visual Studio's Publish option.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass optional properties to the MSBuild script to call MSDeploy (Assuming you have it setup on both the client/server).

**/p:DeployOnBuild=True** – This will let us deploy after build

**/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish** – This set how we will deploy, using MSDeploy

**/p:MSDeployServiceURL=http:///MsDeployAgentService**

**/p:DeployIISAppPath="Default Web Site"** – The path where the app will be deployed

**/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True** – Create a package to deploy the App

**/p:MsDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent** – Server where the MSDeploy is installed. The possible values for this are:

*RemoteAgent* – When the MSDeploy is deployed at another machine

*InProc* – Deploy to the Local IIS

**/p:AllowUntrustedCertificated=True** – Connect to the MSDeployServiceURL without trying to use certificate.

To use a certificate you should use another URL on the MSDeployServiceURL.

**/p:UserName=username** – The username of a user with permission to Deploy the application

**/p:Password=password** – a VALID password for that user :)

Taken from [Allmatech ALM Team](http://blogs.allmatech.com.br/Blogs/ALMTeam/post/Creating-a-Build-Definition-to-work-with-MSDeploy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
xcopy *.* \\server\folder
```